# Can we pass the select fields value parallel two sub transform excutor in Spoon from main transform

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

have Select field step one main transformation and am passing the select field value to two transformation executor parallel

tell me which one execute first or both will execute parallel

I want to execute two transformation parallel in spoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All steps in a transformation are executed at the start of the transformation, they wait for the incoming stream of data, but are started all at the same time.

Comment: I can see the step in UDM Log but output Excel records also in UDM Log When I am checking the excel file mean csv is not their in the dir